# Which element is being scrolled?

Tags: jquery, html-select, jquery-events

I'm making custom select boxes and I need a way to programmaticly detect which of several boxes is being scrolled.

I am trying to mimic the `<select>` functionality when size > 1. That is if you hit [up:38] or [down:40] select the appropriate item in the list.

My fiddle I'm working with http://jsfiddle.net/GtA8v/52/

Now since the event is attached to the body, how do I know which of the '.wrap' elements are being scrolled(hopefully before they are scrolled so I can actually stop the event if needs be)?

EDIT: I updated the Jfiddle if you look I just have place holder for which 'wrap' is being scrolled once I can figure out which 'wrap is received the event it will work as I expect.

Comment: As a side-note: I noticed your scrollbars don't scroll the content when you click the arrows on them to go up and down. To fix this add a `line-height` setting to the `.wrap` style. Similar to this: `.wrap{ height:5em; line-height: 1em; overflow-y:scroll; }`

Comment: @Francois Wahl, this is really close to what I'm looking for. I want the [down40] to add the class 'selected' to the next element and remove it from the current element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UUUUUGGGGGLLLLLYYY but it works, I make note of when a wrap element is focused and then when the selectNext() function is called I just reference that. I'll leave this as the unaccepted answer for a while, to see if someone knows how to establish this from looking at the event object, but this is a solution that works.

http://jsfiddle.net/GtA8v/66/

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use the [`scroll`](http://api.jquery.com/scroll/) event to figure out which of the elements is scrolling.  Example:

```
$('.wrap').scroll(function() {
    console.log($(this));
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/GtA8v/30/)

Comment: Isn't too late to stop the scroll at that point? And how can I tell if  [up] or [down] was pressed at that point?

Comment: I really am looking for the keyup event before the scroll. Which is attached to the body.

Comment: @CynicalOptimist what if the user scrolls using the wheel on their mouse instead of the up and down keys? The waypoints jQuery plugin may be of interest to you: http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/#examples e.g. `someElements.waypoint(function(event, direction) { if (direction === 'down') { // do something } });`

Comment: Really cool stuff! I'm wanting the scroll-wheel to stay the same though. I am sure I'll probably use this in the future though, thanks.